# How can I identify if there is, at least, one capital letter in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

First of all, I'm quite new with Python.

As the title says, I want to identify if a string contains, at least, one capital letter. If not, I will raise an error saying something like *there is no capital letter detected*.
I have found that the `any()` function would help me with that, but when I put it on the function it returns the error `'bool' object is not iterable`.

Here's what I got:

```
def identify_capital(x):
    if any(x.isupper()) == True:
        return True
    else:
        raise ValueError("No capital letter detected")
```

Also, I've tried it with a for loop but it returns the following error `'int' object is not subscriptable`. Here's the code:

```
def identify_capital(x):
    for letter in range(len(x)):
        if letter[i] in x.isupper():
            return True
        else:
            raise ValueError("No capital letter detected")
```

Thanks for your help and, if more information is needed, let me know.

Comment: `return any(letter.isupper() for letter in x)`: this letter is an actual character  -  your `letter` is a NUMBER not the actual letter, there is no `i` in your whole function - and `letter[i]` is nonsensical.

Comment: @VictorLj , You can use just map with a isupper function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `any` function should accept an iterable of `bool` values, not a single `bool` value as returned by `x.isupper()`. Iterate over the characters in the string:

```py
>>> test1 = 'foo bar'
>>> test2 = 'foo Bar'
>>> any(c.isupper() for c in test1)
False
>>> any(c.isupper() for c in test2)
True
```

An alternative way using the regex character class `[A-Z]` to match an uppercase letter:

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.search('[A-Z]', test1)
>>> re.search('[A-Z]', test2)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 5), match='B'>
```

The `re.search` function returns a truthy `Match` object or a falsey `None`, so you can use it in an `if` statement like so:

```py
if re.search('[A-Z]', x):
    ...
```

Comment: And how could I `raise ValueError` if there is not a capital letter? Instead of return False I need to add that. Thanks!

Comment: ...you would write `raise ValueError()` in the branch where there is not a capital letter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use just **map** with a **isupper** *function*

**For example:**

```
s = "abcAs"
contains_upper_case = any(map(str.isupper, s))
print(contains_upper_case)
```